# Why my navigationview overwrites the content of the full FrameLayout

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am trying to place a DrawerLayout to an existing screen. So all screen content i have placed in FrameLayout as shown below picture.

But the moment i include NavigationView (Material navigation), it completely overwrites the content exists in FrameLayout.

Can someone please review, where i am going wrong?

[image: DrawerLayout]

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution to my problem.

The mistake which i made is in NavigationView, i used **layout_gravity="start"**, but which should be **android:layout_gravity="start"**